# Html 5 validation and bootstrap accordian - how do i display the pane that has a validation issue?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I have this html form, and each input item has the `required` attribute as well as a `oninvalid` method.

The fields are broken up in sections using twitter `bootstrap accordion`. e.g. (customer details, address details etc.)

What I need to do is show the pane that has the validation issue to the user when they click on submit.

My Html :

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
              Customer Details
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse customerdetails in">
          <div class="panel-body ">
            <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9 form-column-left">
            <label>Title</label>
             <input oninvalid="ErrorPane('customerdetails')" type="text" title="" data-original-title="" id="custitle" name="mobilePhoneFree" class="form-control " placeholder="Mr / Mrs" value="" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 form-column-left">
            <label>Name & Surname</label>
             <input type="text" oninvalid="ErrorPane('customerdetails')" title="" data-original-title="" id="customername" name="customername" class="form-control " placeholder="Name & Surname" value="" required="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-9 form-column-left">
            <label>ID Type</label>
                  <select class="form-control">
      <option value="SAID">South African ID</option>
      <option value="PASSPORT">Passport</option>
    </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 form-column-left">
            <label>ID/Passport Number</label>
             <input type="text" oninvalid="ErrorPane('customerdetails')" title="" data-original-title="" id="idnumber" name="mobilePhoneFree" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter your mobile number" value="" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 form-column-left">
            <label>Email Address</label>
             <input type="text" oninvalid="ErrorPane('customerdetails')" title="" data-original-title="" id="emailaddress" name="mobilePhoneFree" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter your mobile number" value="" required="">
        </div>
    </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
              Address Details
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse addressdetails ">
          <div class="panel-body ">
            <div class="col-xs-9 form-column-left">
            <label>Address Line 1</label>
             <input oninvalid="ErrorPane('addressdetails')" type="text" title="" data-original-title="" id="address1" name="address1" class="form-control " placeholder="" value="" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 form-column-left">
            <label>Address Line 2</label>
             <input oninvalid="ErrorPane('addressdetails')" type="text" title="" data-original-title="" id="address2" name="address2" class="form-control " placeholder="" value="" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 form-column-left">
            <label>Suburb</label>
             <input oninvalid="ErrorPane('addressdetails')" type="text" title="" data-original-title="" id="suburb" name="suburb" class="form-control " placeholder="" value="" required >
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 form-column-left">
            <label>Postal Code</label>
             <input  oninvalid="ErrorPane('addressdetails')" type="text" title="" data-original-title="" id="postalcode" name="postalcode" class="form-control " placeholder="" value="" required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function ErrorPane(panename){
        $('div.'+panename).collapse('toggle');
    }
</script>
```

If the specific filed does not validate it calls the function `Errorpane`, and passes on the pane's class name it needs to display.

That part works its the showing and hiding of the other panes that don't work. So if there is an error pane 3, pane 1 and 2 shows. I just need that one pane with the issue to display.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#client-side-form-validation An event `invalid` is fired for each invalid element, and you can query the validation state of form elements as well.